# PHP array_intersect() till the first match

Tags: php, arrays, loops, array-intersect

I have 2 arrays to compare and find if there is **at least a single value in common**.

This works just fine:

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$arr2 = array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
if (array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)) {
    // good, at least one match found
}
```

However, the question is performance. It doesn't make sense to continue looping thru the arrays after the first match was found. Is there a native PHP function or a useful snippet to achieve this?

Will a combination of `foreach()` and `in_array()` do the trick?

Comment: can you post your 2 arrays ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 Why does it matter what's in the arrays? I don't think there's anything built-in that does this. But you can use `array_flip` on one of them, and then use a loop on the other that uses `array_key_exists`.

Comment: in_array would internally loop through all of the values of one array for each value in the other so probably no savings there.

Comment: @Orangepill, thru **all** the values? Or will it return once the first match is encountered?

Comment: until first match. If the normal case is points of intersection to exist loop/array_search would probably yield better results on average. If you don't expect matches array intersect is going to be the way to go.

Comment: loop+array_search() VS loop+in_array()? Or that's the same thing?

Comment: in_array may have a (very) slight advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $val) {
    if (in_array($val, $arr2)){
        // do something, maybe return so you wouldn't need break
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this was pretty much exactly what I had in mind. I was just hoping there might be a native function or a parameter for `array_intersect()`

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the first value?

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); 
$arr2 = array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6); 
if (array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)[0]) { 
    // good, at least one match found 
}
```